# Seeding Development database with data from Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, development-environment, production-environment, seeding

I'm dealing with a complex Rails application that uses Postgresql.
Creating seeds from scratch may be too complicated (there are many models and activation steps that can only work in a very specific order).

But I do need some very accurate seeds anyway in order to develop new features.
Is there a way to transfer some data from the production db to the development one?
I would also prefer not to install gems nor modify the production app just for this.

Comment: Download the production database dump and export into your local db.

Comment: Assuming you have access to the production database you should create a dump file as jagdeep said doing:  "pg_dump production_dbname > dumpfile" and then you can restore the dumpfile via:  'psql dev_dbname < dumpfile' using the dev dbs name here.

Answer (score 4):

Tonic (disclaimer: I work there) has an open source solution for subsetting Postgres databases.  Its available on Github and is written in Python.  You can find it here: https://github.com/TonicAI/condenser.

Subsetting is a difficult problem because you have to maintain referential integrity.  Our approach was to build a network graph of the database where Tables are nodes and FK relationships are directed edges (from parent to child).  We then sort the graph via a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and begin removing rows opportunistically.  There is some nuance there and a few gotchas though.  For example, directed graphs can contain cycles and when that happens Topological Sorting will fail.  There is a lot more to it, and you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) (or just clone the repo and have it).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to transfer some data from the production db to the development one?

Dump only specific tables and seed your development database with dumped sql file:

```
pg_dump -d production_database -t table_one -t table_two ... > /tmp/dev_dump.sql
```

[`The pg_dump have good manual`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

But be carefull, frequently tables has foreign keys and other staff.